# Admin theme creation in Drupal

Tags: theming

I am new to drupal and I have a task to create a custom admin theme. I read a lot of tutorial to how to create a theme in drupal and I am familiarize with that. But never see how to create a new admin theme. I also wanted to customize the default `<input type ="text"....>` fields with custom css.
Thank you in advance.. :)

Comment: FYI, there is nothing like `admin theme` and `user theme`, when you create one theme, you can use it on the whole site. `<input type ="text"....>` can be customised with `input[type="text"]`. Also this is a good place to start https://www.drupal.org/documentation/theme

Comment: @NikhilM is right, there is no user/admin theme in Drupal. But in case you want to create a theme, that controls only admin display, where admin works, not the front end of website. You need to make any custom theme and set it **Administration theme**

Comment: @Nikhil M thank you for your quick response. Its ok for me. But my doubt is how can I style my admin in a different way? I just try with style.css and its work, fine. But I don't know its the right thing. Is there any additional css need to modify the admin page?Especially the forms?

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? That being said, if I had to do this, I would create a sub-theme of a really good existing Admin theme such as Adminimal, Seven, or Rubik.  That way you are up and running with all the admin theme features and then it's a simple matter of theming.

Comment: +1 @DannyEnglander, Thats good and well for a fresher as me. Now I follow the same

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For **Admin Theme**

1. Create a custom drupal theme (its already answered).
2. Bring it to your drupal site.
3. Go to **Home » Administration » Appearance**, Select your theme in **Administration theme** select box and save

[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Create A Custom Theme/New theme (Drupal Tutorial)**

This one shows how to create a **Custom Theme** for your drupal site.

1. Create custom.info file
2. Enable the theme
3. Create page.tpl.php and style.css file
4. Bring in the Drupal
5. Some refining
6. The final files

**1. Create custom.info file**

- Create a folder custom in your **sites/all/themes** folder
- Inside it create a file `custom.info` with these lines:

**name = Custom Theme

core = 7.x

engine = phptemplate**

**2. Enable the theme**

- Go to **Appearance** and click '**Enable and set default**' for the **Custom Theme**

**3. Create page.tpl.php and style.css files**

- Create a folder templates in your **sites/all/themes/custom** folder
- Inside it create a file `page.tpl.php`
- Inside the `page.tpl.php` we create our html document for the layout.

**4. Bring in the Drupal**

- Let's do the **navigation** first.
- Go to **Structure | Menus** and add our **navigation links** in Main menu

for more [details](http://www.wdtutorials.com/how-to-create-custom-theme-drupal-tutorial-article/7#.Vi28dn4rIdU)